# quartz cron to fire every 90 min starting midnight

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I want a cron job (or a combination of 2 jobs) which fires at 00:00, 01:30, 03:00 and so on for all day. What can be the most succinct way to write the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to split it into 2 jobs since it is an odd frequency

0 0-21/3 * * * command

30  1-22/3 * * * command

Comment: This looks like the correct solution...didn't know I could write like this "0-21/3". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use following cron expression to configure your cron trigger

```
0 0/30 0,23 * * ?
```

**Also See**

- [Quarts doc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)